# Command to know when it become constant

Tags: differential-equations, equation-solving

So I got this equations and I want to know if there is a command to know when the function becomes constant and obtain that value, this is my code and I know that approximately at 2600 both functions become constant, but this is the number I want to know, at what number it becomes constant.

```
sol = NDSolve[{Ca'[t] == 
    25 - 0.005 Ca[t] - 8 10^12 E^(-22500/(1.987 T[t] )) Ca[t], 
   T'[t] == 
    0.005 (300 - T[t]) + 
     0.01 (8 10^12 E^(-22500/(1.987 T[t] ))) Ca[t] - 
     0.001 (T[t] - 330), Ca[0] == 5000, T[0] == 330}, {Ca, T}, {t, 
   1500}]
Plot[{Ca[t], T[t]} /. sol, {t, 0, 1000}, PlotRange -> All]
Ca[t] /. sol /. t -> 2600
T[t] /. sol /. t -> 2600
```

Many thanks for all the help

Comment: Plotting the numerical solutions you compute, it looks as if the functions do not become exactly constant, but vary slightly.  This might be their true behaviour, or might be some small error in the solution.  I think you need to define more precisely what you mean by "constant".

Comment: You solve the differential equation up to $t=1500$ but then evaluate it at $t=2600$. This extrapolation is not a stable strategy.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We can use `WhenEvent` to collect the data when `Ca'[t]^2` and  `T'[t]^2` smaller enough( Here we set `10^-10`).

```
WhenEvent[Ca'[t]^2 <= 10^-10 && T'[t]^2 <= 10^-10, 
 Print[{t, Ca'[t], T'[t]}]]
```

```
sol = NDSolve[{Ca'[t] == 
    25 - 0.005 Ca[t] - 8 10^12 E^(-22500/(1.987 T[t])) Ca[t], 
   T'[t] == 
    0.005 (300 - T[t]) + 
     0.01 (8 10^12 E^(-22500/(1.987 T[t]))) Ca[t] - 
     0.001 (T[t] - 330), Ca[0] == 5000, T[0] == 330, 
   WhenEvent[Ca'[t]^2 <= 10^-10 && T'[t]^2 <= 10^-10, 
    Print[{t, Ca'[t], T'[t]}]]}, {Ca, T}, {t, 0, 3500}]
```

> `{1712.28,0.00001,-2.57488*10^-8}`

It means that when `t=1712.28`, all of `Ca'[t]^2, T'[t]^2`  became smaller then `10^-10`.

At the end,we can also use `Sow` and `Reap` to collect the `t` and plot it by `MeshShading`.

```
sol = Reap@
   NDSolve[{Ca'[t] == 
      25 - 0.005 Ca[t] - 8 10^12 E^(-22500/(1.987 T[t])) Ca[t], 
     T'[t] == 
      0.005 (300 - T[t]) + 
       0.01 (8 10^12 E^(-22500/(1.987 T[t]))) Ca[t] - 
       0.001 (T[t] - 330), Ca[0] == 5000, T[0] == 330, 
     WhenEvent[Ca'[t]^2 <= 10^-10, Sow[t]]}, {Ca, T}, {t, 0, 3500}];
Plot[{Ca[t], T[t]} /. sol[[1]] // Evaluate, {t, 0, 3000}, 
 PlotRange -> All, AspectRatio -> Automatic,  MeshFunctions -> (#1 &),
  Mesh -> {sol[[2]]}, MeshStyle -> Cyan, 
 MeshShading -> {Automatic, Red}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

The asymptotes can be found by setting the derivatives to zero:

```
FindRoot[{0 == 25 - 0.005 Ca - 8 10^12 E^(-22500/(1.987 T)) Ca,
          0 == 0.005 (300 - T) + 0.01 (8 10^12 E^(-22500/(1.987 T))) Ca - 0.001 (T - 330)},
         {{Ca, 700}, {T, 350}}]

(*    {Ca -> 736.652, T -> 340.528}    *)
```

There is no need to solve the differential equation for this.